Getting data in the dictionary from the main function to another function
I have a dictionary called self.account_summary_data = {} first used in the accountSummary function, specifically the key "BuyingPower", which I was hoping to use in another function. However, I can't seem to get the value of the key "BuyingPower" to execute_strategy(...).
This is part of the script that shows the issue and what it prints:
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.order import Order
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.stock_data = {}
        self.message_printed = {}
        self.latest_price = {}
        self.account_summary_data = {}
        self.risk_per_trade = 4  # in Percentage
        self.buying_power = None
        self.amount_of_shares = None
        self.trailing_stop = None
        self.next_purchase = {}
        globalbuying_power = 0.0
      
        # More code here...
    
    # More code here...

    def accountSummary(self, reqId: int, account: str, tag: str, value: str, currency: str):
        super().accountSummary(reqId, account, tag, value, currency)
        if tag in ["TotalCashValue", "BuyingPower"]:
            print(f"AccountSummary. ReqId: {reqId}, Account: {account}, Tag: {tag}, Value: {value},       Currency: {currency}")
        self.account_summary_data[tag] = value
        print(f"Updated account_summary_data: {self.account_summary_data}"
        buying_power = self.account_summary_data.get('BuyingPower')
        print('buying_power:', buying_power)   
    

    def execute_strategy(self, reqId, atr_value):
        buying_power = self.account_summary_data.get('BuyingPower')
        print('buying_power:', buying_power)
        # Expected: outputs 400000
        # Actual: outputs None        

Result from accountSummary(...): AccountSummary. ReqId: 4, Account: DU008, Tag: BuyingPower, Value: 400000.00, Currency: USD 
Updated self.account_summary_data: {'BuyingPower': '400000.00'} from the accountSummary(...) function.
I haven't figured out what it is, I initially thought it may be a local variable problem, however that doesn't make sense:

I declared it at the top (in __init__)
Typing in the dictionary (self.account_summary_data) in another function highlights it blue, showing it exists

The next thing I tried was declaring a global variable and calling the BuyingPower key to the global variable and print it in execute_strategy(...), and that still didn't work.
In the account summary, I returned the dictionary and called it in execute_strategy(...) and that did work, but now it doesn't seem to work, and I didn't change anything.
